# Running powershell network script at computer startup will fail

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, hyper-v

an Hyper-V Server 2019 attempts to run a network powershell script at computer startup, through the Task Scheduler, however this script will not run at startup, nothing happens.

Once the Hyper-V server has booted, if the script is manually launched through the Task Scheduler, it will run.

Could it be possible that the script will fail to run because the network is not available at that time?

[image]

Comment: Yes this may be possible. You may wait some time in the script for the network share to be available.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Hazrelle, delaying the script start for 5 minutes did the trick. I have followed instructions in this article:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/start-scheduled-tasks-with-delay-windows/